# NUnit says the test was successful

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, nmock

I am new to Unit Testing.  The Unit Tests are succeeding in the below.  I expect them to fail because Student.getCourse, unidergraduate.getCourse1 and postgraduate.getcourse1 return different values to what is being tested for e.g. "Student Course" <> "Student Course 1".

```
Imports NUnit.Framework
Imports NMock
Imports StudentCL

Namespace Test

    <TestFixture()>
    Public Class StudentTest
        Private _mocks As MockFactory
        Private _StudentMock As Mock(Of Student)
        Private _GraduateMock As Mock(Of Graduate)
        Private _UndergraduateMock As Mock(Of UnderGraduate)

        <SetUp()>
        Public Sub SetUp()
            _mocks = New MockFactory()
            _StudentMock = _mocks.CreateMock(Of Student)()
            _GraduateMock = _mocks.CreateMock(Of Graduate)()
            _UndergraduateMock = _mocks.CreateMock(Of UnderGraduate)()
        End Sub

        <Test()>
        Public Sub getStudentCourse()
            _StudentMock.Expects.One.Method(Function(x) x.getCourse1).WillReturn("Student Course1")
        End Sub

        <Test()>
        Public Sub getGraduateCourse()
            _GraduateMock.Expects.One.Method(Function(x) x.getCourse1).WillReturn("Graduate Course1")
        End Sub

        <Test()>
        Public Sub getUndergraduateCourse()
            _UndergraduateMock.Expects.One.Method(Function(x) x.getCourse1).WillReturn("Undergraduate Course1")
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace

Public MustInherit Class Student
    Public Overridable Function getCourse1() As String
        Return "Student course"
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Graduate
    Inherits Student

    Public Overrides Function getCourse1() As String
        Return "Graduate course"
    End Function

End Class

Public Class UnderGraduate
    Inherits Student

    Public Overrides Function getCourse1() As String
        Return "Undergraduate course"
    End Function

End Class
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Your code isn't actually testing anything. It is simply setting up mocks. By themselves, mocks are useless. From what you've written, it appears you want to test the result of the `getCourse1` function. An example of one of your tests might look like the following.

```
<Test()> _
Public Sub getCourse1_WhenCalled_ReturnsExpected()
    ' Arrange
    Dim student As New Graduate()

    ' Act
    Dim course As String = student.getCourse1()

    ' Assert
    Assert.That(course, Iz.EqualTo("Graduate Course1")) ' This will fail as you expected.
End Sub
```

The test method name follows a convention described in the book *The Art of Unit Testing*. The test body is arranged in a sequence known as the AAA pattern.

Comment: Thanks +1.  Doesn't the following line ensure test if Undergraduate.getCourse1 returns: "Undergraduate Course1": _UndergraduateMock.Expects.One.Method(Function(x) x.getCourse1).WillReturn("Undergraduate Course1")

Comment: That only applies if the mock is used. The mock is never used, so the condition was never verified. Also, the mock is not an actual instance of your class. Your code isn't testing your class, it's simply creating a fake version of your class and saying that if x.getCource1 is called then return "Undergraduate Cource1". The mock must be verfied at the end of the test to check the 'Expects.One' condition. In your case, there is no need for mocks.

Comment: Thanks.  What is Expects.one.method used for? I cannot find any reference material.

Comment: I don't use NMock. However, I imagine it works similar to other Mock frameworks. It sets up an expected call to 'getCourse1' to happen one time that is called by some other object. At the end of the test, the mock is verified to ensure that the one call happened. So in your tests, the mocks are set up to be used by an object that uses the Student class and to test that it uses your Student class correctly, not to test your Student classes themselves.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of how to use: expects.one.method.willreturn using my classes? I will then be in a position to mark this answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: I could make up something, but I don't know how helpful that would be as I don't know what you're trying to accomplish. If you're trying to test your Student classes, then using a mock is the wrong thing to do.  Mocks shouldn't be introduced until they are necessary. You aren't showing a need for them.